# Add scalacheck dependency to gradle project

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I am trying to use scalaCheck (https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck) to a gradle project. However, adding it this way:

```
 dependencies {
 ...
      compile group: 'org.scalacheck', name: 'scalacheck_2.11', version: '1.12.5'
 ...
 }
```

doesn't seem to be doing the trick. I also tried to add it in a maven project. In both cases, trying to do the following

```
 import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll
```

reports the error

```
 object scalacheck is not a member of package org
```

I ran "gradle dependencies" before trying to import it, and it seemed to download everything just fine, finishing the command without throwing errors. Is there a way to add scalacheck to my project and if so, how?

Note: not sure if relevant, but I am using Eclipse Neon with all the scala plugins.

Comment: Have you tried the Gradle | Refresh Gradle Project from the project's context menu?

Comment: @GáborBakos Who would have thought it was related to Gradle and not Scala... Worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(So it seems the problem was with using the eclipse gradle integration.) You have to manually update the project by using the `Gradle` | `Refresh Gradle` Project from the project's context menu on each dependency change (though it might be useful to do that on each change to gradle configuration files).